# New-AzureRmKeyVault : 'vaultName' does not match expected pattern

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-keyvault

I am trying to set up Azure Key Vault for my application by following this tutorial: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/kv/2015/06/02/azure-key-vault-step-by-step/

In the Create and configure key vault section in the tutorial, Right after doing these two steps:
[image]

I am not able to do this step:
[image]

It shows error message in my PowerShell:

> New-AzureRmKeyVault : 'vaultName' does not match expected pattern '^[a-zA-Z0-9-]{3,24}$'.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + New-AzureRmKeyVault -VaultName ProfileKeyVault -ResourceGro ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureRmKeyVault], ValidationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.KeyVault.NewAzureKeyVault

Comment: you probably should mask your subscription id

Comment: vaultName is probalby allready in use, try a different one

Comment: In my situation I got this error msg when was trying to add KV secret name with "_". Example: Set-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName "kvName" -Name "Cert_ToResource" -SecretValue $variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting the vault name in quotes.

```
New-AzureRmKeyVault -VaultName 'Contoso03Vault' -ResourceGroupName 'Group14' -Location 'East US'
```

Answer (score 0):

When I got the error

> 'vaultName' does not match expected pattern

I found using Powershell with raw Az CLI Commands you have to use Double Quotes to **create** the KeyVault.

```
az keyvault create --name "vault-Name-01" --resource-group $resourceGroupName --location $location --sku Standard --enabled-for-disk-encryption true
```

In a Powershell script you pass in the variable wrapped with double quotes

```
[string]$vaultName = "vault-Name-01"
az keyvault create --name $vaultName --resource-group $resourceGroupName --location $location -sku Standard --enabled-for-disk-encryption true
```

Then when you want to **set** a value you remove the double quotes:

```
az keyvault secret set --vault-name $vaultName.Replace("`"","") --name $_.name  --value  $_.value
```

---

Further investigation reveals the problem applies to **listing** and **showing** the vault secrets and I bumped into the infamous error:

**Max retries exceeded attempting to connect to vault. The vault may not exist or you may need to flush your DNS cache and try again later.**

The KeyVault exists, because I can list the vaults secrets using the VaultName without quotes:

```
$secretNames = az keyvault secret list --vault-name $sourceVaultName.Replace("`"","") -o json --query "[].name"  | ConvertFrom-Json
```

However you'll get the Max Retires error if you don't include a quoted `$sourceVaultName` when trying to **show** the secrets:

```
$secrets = $secretNames | % {
    $secret = az keyvault secret show --name $_ --vault-name $sourceVaultName -o json | ConvertFrom-Json
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        name  = $_;
        value = $secret.value;
    }
}
```

If any of these calls timeout and the result is blank refer to this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67472219/495455

It's almost like two developers worked on the code and had different opinions... https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/13952