# az keyvault does not list secret

Tags: azure-cli, azure-cloud-shell

I'm using **azure cli** from the **windows terminal** azure cloud shell. 
I expect `az keyvault secret list --vault-name myKeyVaultName` to list all the secrets in my vault 
**but it only shows me a black screen**. 
What am I doing wrong? Any Suggestions?

Comment: Could you please check if you have right permissions to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the exact same error a few days ago with `az keyvault secret list`, and tried running the command with the `--debug` parameter:

```
az keyvault secret list --vault-name <key-vault-name> --debug
```

Also refreshed my credentials by running `az login` again but no luck. After some troubleshooting and looking through logs, I realized I had passed the incorrect vault name in the command.

A similar [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/13952) on GitHub also mentions that this error can surface in case of an incorrect key vault name as the error message calls out. If none of these help, you can open a new bug report with the [Azure/azure-cli](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/new/choose) repo with the error details.

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71580218/495455